# Laptop overheats with ubuntu 14.04 while stay cool with windows 7

Tags: nvidia, asus, overheating

I have an Asus N53SN laptop. It has both nvidia and intel integrated gpu. I am using nvidia-prime with restricted drivers.

When idle, heat levels stay low, but whenever I watch a movie or youtube, heat rises to 78-80°C in both gpu's. In Windows I only get maximum 60°C.

Comment: Same here on a Qosmio-X770 with Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and bumblebee.
Im thinking of modding the back cover to improve airflow since i was not able to find any better solutions.

Most games cause the computer to close due to overheating protection.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem with a fresh install on my laptop. What works for me is the following:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings
```

Then run:

```
nvidia-settings
```

And under the PRIME Profiles tab on the left of the Nvidia settings window switch to your Intel GPU instead of Nvidia GPU.